# Are Modules listed under /sys/module all the Loaded Modules?

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, sysfs

I'm wondering if I can use the directory listing of `/sys/module` instead of lsmod to get a list of currently loaded modules.

Is that the list of loaded modules only? Or maybe that combined with `/sys/module/*/initstate`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Each loaded module has an entry in `/sys/module`. But there are also kernel components with an entry in `/sys/module` that are not loaded as modules. Each kernel component¹ that *can* be built as a module has an entry in `/sys/module`, whether it is compiled and loaded as a module or compiled as part of the main kernel image.

`lsmod` gets the list of loaded modules from `/proc/modules`.

I think that only loaded modules have an `initstate` file in their `/sys/module` directory, so you can use that too.

¹  <sub>That's each component of the loaded kernel. The kernel doesn't know or care what modules you may have in files on your hard disk. The kernel doesn't care what modules were built at the same time of the kernel image, either; it may show that via `/proc/config` but it doesn't use that information for anything.</sub>

Comment: A fun side effect is that you can't insmod modules that are named exactly like built-in modules and you become totally clueless why: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364956/how-can-insmod-fail-with-kernel-module-is-already-loaded-even-is-lsmod-does-not

Comment: @Gilles I was wondering if you could clarify "Each kernel component that can be built as a module has an entry in /sys/module". On my system: `lsmod | wc -l` => 116. `ls /sys/module | wc -l` = >201.  `grep '=m' /boot/config-$(uname -r)` => 4934.

Comment: @catanman That's the loaded modules. Usually you would only load a small number of modules compared to the number that were built, and you may load modules that were built separately.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks. Just to make sure I get it: If I do `grep '=y' /boot/config-$(uname -r) | wc -l` => 2389. Out of all 2389 components statically compiled into the kernel, only 201-116=85 of them could have been compiled/loaded as modules. 2389-85=2304 could not be loaded as modules (therefore they can only be set to `y` or `n` in the config file). Does this make sense?

Comment: No. You have 2389 options set to `y`, not all of which are components (some are yes/no settings but not a distinct component). You have 4934 components available as modules. You have 116 loaded modules, and 201-116=85 components that could be loaded as modules, but are built in.

Comment: Got it! Couple more questions :). **1)** For options set to `y` how would I go about determining which are components vs simple yes/no settings. **2)** For each options set to `m`, there is one corresponding ".ko" file that is built (stored at /lib /modules/$(uname -r) on my system) **3)** Even if a component is set to `n` at build time, it is possible to load that component as a module if you obtain the ".ko" file.

Comment: @catanman 1) Look in the `Kconfig` files in the kernel source (either directly or via a kernel configuration tool). 2) Yes. 3) Yes (but you'd need to have a compatible `.ko` file, which is hard to ensure unless the file was built from the same kernel version with the same options).

Comment: It untrue that all modules show up in `/sys/modules`. On Ubuntu 20.04, `ext4` is builtin and there is no corresponding `/sys/module/ext4`.

Comment: @Melab Is this a recent change? I'm reading this on Ubuntu 18.04 and it does have `/sys/module/ext4`.