# difference between /lib/module/$(uname -r) and /sys/module

Tags: linux, kernel-modules

I apologize if the query is too simple. But I want to ask is there a difference between linux system modules and linux kernel modules. If there is a difference then where are both located. Is it that /lib/module/$(uname -r) shows kernel modules and /sys/module/ shows system modules

Comment: Thanks for the edit, would be helpful if you can help me with the solution . Its my first moth working on Linux machines :)

Comment: I was just writing an answer :)

Comment: lol, thanks for the ans. So in nut shell system and kernel modules are the same thing right ?

Comment: AFAIK Yes, when speaking about "modules" in Linux, it generally refers to "kernel modules". In a nutshell `/sys/module` shows all modules by name, `/lib/module/$(uname -r)` has all the modules' file organized by function.
Please, don't forget to vote/accept answers if they solved your question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory `/sys/module/` shows all modules in the system by their name as folders with diverse information needed by the system. The directory `/lib/module/$(uname -r)` contains the kernel module files, stored in a folder hierarchy according to their function.

For example, the Software Watchdog kernel module file would be in `/lib/module/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/watchdog/softdog.ko`. 
On the other hand, this module has its own "softdog" (the module name) directory in `/sys/module/` with information used by the system when operating/inserting this module, but not the file of the module itself.

You can operate modules by name with `modprobe [args] <module-name> [module-params]`

You can operate modules by path to the `.ko` file with `insmod [args] <path> [module-params]`.

Mind that operating kernel modules requires root privileges.

Answer (score 4):

`/lib/module/$(uname -r)` is a directory on your disk¹. It contains files, most of which (`*.ko`) are module files: files that contain the code of a kernel module. The files in this directory (and its subdirectories) contain, in principle, modules that you can load into your running kernel.

`/sys/module` is a directory on a virtual filesystem that exposes kernel internals. Accessing a file in that directory invokes a function in the kernel which only looks at some internal kernel data structures, it doesn't go any further to a disk layer. Each entry in `/sys/module` corresponds to a component of the running kernel, with code that's loaded in memory and active. This includes all loaded modules, but also components that could be loaded as a module but were built directly into the kernel when the kernel was compiled.

Having files in `/lib/module/$(uname -r)` that don't correspond to an entry in `/sys/module` is very common: they're drivers for some piece of hardware (or other thing managed by the kernel) that you don't have in your computer. Entries in `/sys/module` with no corresponding file under `/lib/module/$(uname -r)` happen when the component was built into the kernel ([here's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225706/are-modules-listed-under-sys-module-all-the-loaded-modules) how to tell), or if the module was loaded manually from a file that's located elsewhere (or is now deleted).

¹  <sub>Or rarely on something other than a disk, if your system keeps its root filesystem elsewhere, e.g. over the network or in a RAM disk.</sub>