# How can insmod fail with kernel module is already loaded, even is lsmod does not contain that module?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, buildroot

I'm making a minimal Linux distro with buildroot to learn kernel module development.

If I call a minimal module `hello.ko` (or almost any other name I've tried), everything works fine.

However, if I use the exact same code, but call the module `workqueue.ko`, `insmod workqueue.ko` fails, dmesg contains:

```
workqueue: module is already loaded
```

and `insmod` outputs to stderr:

```
insmod: can't insert 'workqueue.ko': invalid argument
```

Both `lsmod` and `cat /proc/modules` are empty.

This is [the exact repo](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/c4b4f029d48e75dddbb6d41b2edafcd2bda5462e) that produced the problem.

For reference the module code is:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

int init_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "hello init\n");
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "hello cleanup\n");
}
```

and the kernel version (default implied by buildroot) is 4.9.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ uname -a
Linux alan-laptop 4.10.14-200.fc25.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed May 3 22:52:30 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ ls /sys/module/workqueue/
parameters  uevent
$ ls /sys/module/workqueue/parameters/
debug_force_rr_cpu  disable_numa  power_efficient
```

It's a builtin already.  Maybe to provide a namespace for the parameters that effect kernel workqueue behaviour.

Comment: Hmmm, can you find where in the source that gets created? I could not find any settings in `.config`. Why not just use other `/sys` files that don't conflict with module names?

Comment: @CiroSantilli709大抓捕六四事件法轮功 You know how to define a module, you can just use `git grep` to search for a definition of the module `workqueue`.

Comment: @CiroSantilli包子露宪六四事件法轮功 that's not what the link says. It is `/sys/module/` that shows builtins like this "workqueue".  They don't show up in `/proc/modules`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I copied wrong.

Comment: fun fact: some things under `/sys/module` are not necessarily moduels it seems https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225706/are-modules-listed-under-sys-module-all-the-loaded-modules/225746#225746