# How to list built-in kernel modules usage stats as lsmod does?

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-modules

As `lsmod` can be executed to result the installed modules that are built with M or externally and their stats (usage), how would the same happen to the built-in kernel modules, I'm curious. I hope someone else answer

Comment: As far as I understand built-in modules are part of the kernel and thus they no longer can be considered "modules" which means they are always active as long as they are used.

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is # cat /sys/module/ :)

Comment: Thank you anyway Artem man

Comment: it list both of them, there you may find good information if they are being used. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/225746/490956